# Tick rate сервера

Tags: сервер

Что такое тик рейт у сервера ?

Comment: переодичность обмена данными с сервером

Answer (score 1):

Было бы неплохо указать, что под этим подразумевался игровой сервер.

1. Tickrate - Единица измерения отправки и получения данных с сервера
       в секунду
2. rate - количество байтов, который клиент может получить
       от сервера за секунду
3. cl_updaterate - количество пакетов, который
       клиент может получить от сервера [Информация о других игроках вам]
4. cl_cmdrate - количество пакетов, который клиент может отослать
       серверу [Информация о вас другим игрокам]

Вот [тут](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=746334996) даже показаны отличия